# Invalid conversion error when trying to keep array from changing when called by a function

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, constants

For this assignment, I need to make a sorted copy of an array the user has given values to. All of my code works as intended, except for this specific part. I need this function (sortedCopy) to print out the sorted version of their array, without actually changing the array itself. As far as I can tell, to do so I need to used a constant version of the array in the function so the prototype would be something like: int *sortedCopy(const int *array, int size), but all this does is give the error shown in the title. Specifically:

```
main.cpp:72:29: error: assignment of read-only location '*(array + 
((sizetype)(((long unsigned int)i) * 4)))' array[i] = array[min]
```

and it does this error twice, except with array[min] = temp; at the end instead

This is the code used, with the relevant parts of main:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* sortedCopy(const int *array, int size) {
    int i, j, min, temp;
    for (i = 0 ; i < size - 1; i++) {
        min = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[min]) {
                min = j;
            }
        }
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[min];
        array[min] = temp;
    }
    cout << "Sorted array is: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    // Not sure if I need to return anything or not either
}

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter the size of the array." << endl;
    int arraySize;
    int array[arraySize]; 
    cin >> arraySize;
    cout << "Please enter integer values until the array is filled." << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i != arraySize; i++) {
        cout << "Value " << (i + 1) << ": "; 
        cin >> array[i];
        cout << endl;
    sortedCopy(array, arraySize);
    for (int i = 0; i != arraySize; i++) { // I want this part to print the 
    cout << array[i] << " ";               // original array entered by the user
    }
}
```

If I remove the const part of the function, it works totally fine, except it will print the sorted array after the function is called, instead of the original array.

Comment: `// Not sure if I need to return anything or not either` If you promise to return an `int*` (or any other non void type) breaking that promise is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: `int* sortedCopy(const int *array, int size)` should probably create a new array dynamically and return that new array not modifying the original array that you are trying to do now.

Comment: `int arraySize;`
`int array[arraySize];`
`cin >> arraySize;` you create array with undefined size. Also note that static arrays of non-constant length are not part of the C++ standard

Comment: Also - it's probably just a typo from copying to stackoverflow, but - you need a close bracket after your first for loop.

In general, when using stackoverflow, try to make your questions as small and simple as possible while still representing the original problem (in this case, the compiler complaining because of the "const"). This often means making the example code do something very different compared to the programme where you first encountered the problem.
This help with debugging for yourself, and saves us readers a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, C/C++ is best read "top-down":

```
int arraySize;
int array[arraySize]; // arraySize is undefined here!!
cin >> arraySize;
```

On the second line, ArraySize, might be 1, or 0, or -1000. You haven't defined it until line 3.
Also, C++ doesn't allow you to allocate arrays of variable size (unless that size is const [ so it is known at compilation time]):

```
int array[4];
```

The above is fine. This helps the operating system know how much memory to provide for you on the stack (it needs to do this before your programme starts running).

```
const int arraySize = 4;
int array[arraySize];
```

Because the C++ compiler knows that arraySize is 4, it processes this just like the above code, so this is also fine.

So to handle arrays of genuinely variable length (length that depends on inputs), you need to first read the user inputs, *then* use dynamic allocation ("new", or a container that does dynamic allocation for you, like a vector).

As for the problem with "const", what I think that you need to understand here is that "const" is really just a promise from the programmer: The programmer is communicating to the compiler (and any programmers reading the code) that this data is not supposed to change. All the compiler does is check whether you keep your promise (or if you send it to another function / pointer that *doesn't* hold that promise). So by using "const" there is no work done being done for you to actually keep the data constant - just that it will complain if *you* don't do the work.

```
int* sortedCopy(const int *array, int size) {
```

Above you're flagging to the compiler that the *sortedCopy* function will keep the data in the array constant.

```
    array[i] = array[min];
    array[min] = temp;
```

And here (above) you are breaking that promise.

If you don't want to edit the original array, then the easiest solution is just to copy it before you send it to your sorting function.

Comment: This is the code I've come up with to correct the first part:
    `cout << "Please enter the size of the array." << endl;
    int arraySize;
    cin >> arraySize;
    int *array; `
I'm hoping I did that properly, although I am still new to dynamic memory allocation so please let me know if I did that the proper way...

Otherwise, yeah simply copying the array into another did the trick, thank you very much for your answer! I should add that I have ` delete[] array; ` a the very bottom of main. I also apologize for the poor formatting, I'm not sure how/if you can make paragraphs in these

Comment: I can't edit that last comment, because I already have recently, but I wanted to add something to the code in the first part, which I seem to have accidentally not included. This is it: `array = new int[arraySize];` and that would come after `int *array;`

Comment: @Spago, Short answer: That won't work. With stackoverflow you should always spend some time googling the problem before coming here to ask. In this case googling "c++ dynamic allocation" or "c++ new" will provide a comprehensive explanation as to how to make any array whose size is dependent on the user inputs.